# JavaScript line continuation not working on test environment

Tags: javascript

The following code is giving me an error on my local environment:

```
previewsContainer: '.images-holder',
previewTemplate: '  <div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview image-input-wrap">\
<div class="dz-loading-icon"><i class="aficon-circle-notch aficon-spin"></i></div>\
<div class="dz-details">\
....
```

In FireFox:

```
SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break
```

In chrome:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

**I understand I could fix this error using `+` to concatanate Strings, but why am I getting this error when running locally? I've ensured all the exact same files are used (Using WinMerge).**

I am serving the JS/other files using an apache webserver both locally & on the live server. Both are linux servers.

**Edit:**

**Just to double clarify I am wondering what could cause this error to only occur on one environment? I'd like to match my local environment to the production one as much as possible. I am at a loss as to what could cause a JS interpretation/execution difference server-side**

Answer (score 0):

Try using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for multiline strings

Answer (score 0):

You can use backticks (template literals) for multi-line strings:

```js
{
  previewTemplate: `<div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview image-input-wrap">
<div class="dz-loading-icon"><i class="aficon-circle-notch aficon-spin"></i></div>
<div class="dz-details">`
}
```